# Java Heap space error while upload 600MB file to nexus via gradle 4.5

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, devops, nexus

I am using gradle 4.5 while uploading 600MB file to nexus i am getting java heap space error vai jenkins what could be the issue.

i tried below but no luck

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Djavafx.embed.singleThread=true"]
```

alos tried

```
apply plugin: 'java'
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Xms1024m","Xmx6144m"]
```

Comment: I think we need a bit more information to be able to assist you. Could you please provide the stack trace, and perhaps any supporting logs?

Comment: the issue could be, you know, _not enough heap_?

Comment: This `["-Xms1024m","Xmx6144m"]` has a minus sign on one parameter and not the other. Can this work?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the out of mem error is not caused by the build, it's caused by the upload , right?

If so, I would try to add the following line to the `gradle.properties` file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2g
```

See the [gradle.properties documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) for more information.